# The connection "" is not found. SSIS

Tags: ssis

When I open a new simple SSIS Project I created I get an error:

'Error loading HyperionFlatLoads.dtsx: The connection "" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
C:\Users...\Projects\Hyperion_Load_Actuals\Hyperion_Load_Actuals\HyperionFlatLoads.dtsx

I've looked everywhere for this reference and can't for the life of me figure out what it's missing.  The package runs fine; the data moves into the SQL table - but this error persists.  Anyone want to help me find out why and eliminate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view and edit dtsx file as regular XML file. So, open it and find

```
<DTS:ConnectionManagers>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager ... DTS:ObjectName="CM name">
```

if you are using SSIS 2012+
or

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager>
...
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">CM name</DTS:Property>
```

if you are on SSIS 2008.
Remove node `<DTS:ConnectionManager>` and save the file.

Comment: If I removed the node and save the file won't I lose the other connections I already have?  It's only two, I could remake them - but I'm trying to learn/understand why this happened and how to prevent it in the future...

Comment: If you remove only <DTS:ConnectionManager> node you will be done. On why it happened - sorry, no idea; somehow package was changed

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an alternative solution that I was facing for others who may stumble across this post.

I had setup logging, but forgot to specify a connection manager. This took me forever to find because viewing the XML doesn't make it obvious where `""` is.

[image]

Comment: I've just faced the same problem. In my case it wasn't blank but was filled with another connection string. I guess that it was possible because I made this package from another.

Comment: This was the solution to my issue and think it will be to many others who have the same problem. Thank you for putting this out there.